# Is there a story behind the misquote, "Luke, I am your father"?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader, the-empire-strikes-back, quotes

I've wondered for a long time how a **misquote** of the famous reveal in The Empire Strikes Back crystalized in pop culture history rather than Vader's actual line:

> No, *I* am your father.

How did the popularization of the misquote occur?

Comment: It's about contextualization. To simply say the actual quote doesn't cue the reader in to the reference as much as prefacing it with "Luke". It's similar to how Kirk never said "Beam me up Scotty". Getting the idea across is important than the actual words used.

Comment: So you're suggesting it just naturally occurred among fans who wanted to make sure they were quoting in a way that people knew what they were talking about? And then it just stuck?

Comment: Pretty much. It's fairly common actually. See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beam_me_up,_Scotty#Similar_misquotations

Comment: @Mwr247 - Hmmf, I always figured it was misquoted in a famous commercial, talk show, or interview somewhere and was popularized because of that. Kind of disappointing if you're right.

Comment: Added as an answer. These sorts of quote alterations are particularly interesting, ad they occasionally make their way back into the originating media as well. For "Beam me up Scotty", William Shatner as Captain Kirk says it in an audio adaptation well after it had been popularized. Likewise with "Elementary, my dear Watson" having appeared in none of the original works by Doyle, but has shown up in later adaptations.

Comment: It can be quoted as "Luke ... I am your father"

Comment: I didn't even realize that he doesn't actually say "Luke, I am your father" until I read this question. Also interesting is that when people quote this line, they put a lot of emphasis into the "Luke" part that you would think it was part of the original dialogue.

Comment: Semantically it would be the same as if he had said "No Luke, I am your father" and then it's a simple matter of dropping the "No" off the front.

Comment: @Andrew - If I remember right, there's some sort of Force telepathy that goes back and forth at the very end of the movie that goes something like, "Luke...", "Father!", That very well could be where the Luke part came from.

Comment: See also, "Alas, poor Yorrick, I knew him *well*". Even Shakespeare is not immune to being widely misquoted, and in this case probably for the exact same reason (i.e., the real quote doesn't make sense without the context).

Comment: Maybe the direct quote came from time travelers who were quoting the next version after the next retroconning takes effect.

Comment: @TheIronCheek ... **"Hmmf, I always figured it was misquoted in a famous commercial, talk show, or interview somewhere and was popularized because of that. Kind of disappointing if you're right"** Of course you are **correct**, obviously.  To state that "it just happens" is not sensible.

Comment: The same way that Morpheus is always quoted as saying, "What if I told you...", but he never did. It *sounds* like something he would say, and you can hear it in your head, and you've heard people claim it enough that you just assume it's all correct.

Comment: @TheIronCheek it doesn't have to have occurred in a specific highly public forum, although it certainly did occur in several.  Tracing the first public appearance of the term would do nothing to trace its true origins, as it was almost certainly said independently by different people (as are most common phrases).

Comment: @Mwr247 Funnily, "Scotty, beam us up fast" is in TOS, and plain "Scotty, beam me up" _ST IV: The Voyage Home_

Comment: Not much of a misquote, because he's talking to Luke, and if you pull it out of the movie, it's quicker and easier to write "Luke.... I am your father" than "no, I am your father (speaking to Luke Skywalker)"

Comment: See also [“Play it again, Sam”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Play_it_again,_Sam) — believe it or not, most people are more interested with saying something that sounds good, rather than quoting accurately.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

### Contextualization matters more than words

In common speech, the quote is fairly vague, and likely only those who have seen the movie would understand the reference (at least, right away, to the desired effect). But by prefacing it with "Luke", you cue people in to the reference better by offering more context.

It's quite similar to how Kirk never said "[Beam me up Scotty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beam_me_up,_Scotty)" during the run of Star Trek. To simply say "Beam me up" might be more accurate, but throwing in the name is better. Getting the idea across is more important than the actual words used, and it's [fairly common](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beam_me_up,_Scotty#Similar_misquotations).

These sorts of quote alterations are particularly interesting, in that they occasionally make their way back into the originating media as well. For "Beam me up Scotty", William Shatner as Captain Kirk says it in an audio adaptation well after it had been popularized. Likewise with "[Elementary, my dear Watson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherlock_Holmes#.22Elementary.2C_my_dear_Watson.22)" having appeared in none of the original works by Doyle, but has shown up in later adaptations.

Comment: The same can be said of "Play it again Sam" which was never actually used in Casablanca.

Comment: What's funny is "Scotty, beam me up" appears.

Comment: A notable counterexample: "Alas, poor Yorick!  I knew him well." is a common but _less_ contextualized misquotation of _Hamlet_'s original, "Alas, poor Yorick! I knew him, Horatio."

Comment: @Psychonaut I'd venture to guess that leaving off the end name is still enough context to get the point across, and the inclusion of "Alas, poor Yorick!" was considered more vital to the idea than ", Horatio". A very good counterexample though.

Comment: `"likely only those who have seen the movie would understand the reference"` Yes, all three of the people who haven't seen Star Wars will be confused for a few seconds.

Comment: @reirab While this used to be the case, as time have moved forward there actually has been a growing number of the younger generation that hasn't seen them.

Comment: The Mandela effect.

Comment: @reirab Hey, I haven't seen Star Wars! Nor do I intend to, for that matter.

Comment: Another example: "Elementary my dear Watson" is never said.

Answer (score 8):

First off, it's arguably NOT! a misquote of the "whole Star Wars canon and universe" since in

## 1983

it was, apparently, actually **read that way** in the

## [Radio version of Star Wars !](https://web.archive.org/web/20160325031410if_/http://scifi.about.com:80/od/starwarsfilms/fr/SWAR_radio-drama.htm)

Found by reirab.

The earliest misquote meme-starting reference, using the "name-first" form,  found so far is

## 1995

in Tommy Boy, found by Jesse Sielaff:

The earliest misquote meme-starting reference, using the "name-first" form, which I found is

## 1999

In the Austin Powers film.

Obviously, The Empire Strikes Back was in **1980**.  I'm sure, someone can find an earlier misquote meme-starting reference, but this will get the ball rolling. (Jessie did!)

***Not all, but many,*** "famous misquotes" come from some *particular* at the time popular source which instanced the misquote. For example, it could be a TV news show at the time, perhaps a cast member being interviewed, or a parody on TV or film.

So, maybe someone can find an even earlier example, but there you go, 1999; now 1995.

Comment: As someone who lived through the release of all three Star Wars movies, I assure you that people were saying, "Luke, I am your father" in the months immediately following the movie and not because of some misquoting in some other media source. This kind of quote "mutation" happens all the time with movies in a similar way. Our brains aren't so good at remembering things perfectly, but we remember how big a moment it was, so we fill in the cracks in our memory so we can try to bring that moment to other people.

Comment: "As someone who lived through the release of all three Star Wars movies, I assure you that ... in the months immediately..." it's incredible you have that good a memory for oldsters of our age, Todd!  I can't remember what continent I was living on in the 70s.  :)

Comment: Now that you mention it, I think my memory is just *focused*. For example, I just now remembered that there are actually like seven Star Wars movies now.

Comment: @ToddWilcox You say "lived through" as if it was a war zone or something...

Comment: @JoeBlow If you remember what continent you lived on in the 70s, you were not in the 70s :)

Comment: @ToddWilcox is correct. However, I think JB is also correct that there has to be some kind of "misquoter zero" who first used this particular verbiage which everyone else picked up and ran with. It's unlikely to be in a clip available on youtube though.

Comment: @T.E.D. I dunno about that. Who's to say that is *wasn't* everyone making the same "mistake," all over at around the same time? It's not like this is such a huge departure in the *meaning* of the line, just one word ([which adds a lot to contextualization](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/126089/41144)) changed.

Comment: Sure:  Situation "A".  It was caused by **one particular notable misquote**.  (So for example, we could actually discover that, literally, (for example) *"Dan Rather on January 1982 misquoted, and it seems to have taken off from there."*  OK?)  **OR**, situation "B". As many have argued, it is an "obvious" misquote so there is **no particular source**: folks just "started doing it", reinforcing each other and it would be incorrect to think of some "particular first famous happening".  OK, so **BOTH** "A" and "B" are perfectly reasonable, and both are possible.  Neither are "impossible".

Comment: However, note that with such misquotes, **indeed "A" is often the case**.  There is a specific actual "first misquoter".  Folks who here are suggesting "only B is possible" are wrong.  (Conversely, if you think "A" *must* be the case - you are wrong.)  I've given an actual decisive "A-like" example: if someone found other "A-like" examples (hopefully far earlier than mine), that would be a Good Thing.  But again - by all means - both "A" and "B" could, certainly, be the explanation here.

Comment: It appeared at least once earlier on film, in Tommy Boy (1995): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TsI3lFHkU_s

Comment: @JesseSielaff :  Brilliant

Comment: @JoeBlow Both are possible, but 'B' seems a lot more likely in this case. Certainly, as others have said, this phrase was in common usage _way_ before 1995.

Comment: Hi @reirab !  if you say "this phrase was in common usage way before 1995" you should surely be able to find in print or video, some example of that.  That would be great.  It would support your case, too.

Comment: @JoeBlow Apparently the line was even [used in a radio dramatization](http://scifi.about.com/od/starwarsfilms/a/3-Famous-Star-Wars-Quotes-That-Were-Never-Said.htm) as early as [1983](http://scifi.about.com/od/starwarsfilms/fr/SWAR_radio-drama.htm). That said, others have already posted personal experience from the months following the movie, which is not particularly surprising.

Comment: brilliant find, @reirab !  following http://english.stackexchange.com standards, personal recollections mean nothing, only references mean anything.  Note too that, indeed, everyone agrees that the misquote has "always been known".  It's entirely possible that, just after the film was released, some "famous misquoting" happened (on a TV show - whatever) and that is *why* we all started misquoting it early.  (I simply don't know if it's a case of "A" or "B", but as already repeated one can't dismiss either.)

Comment: @JoeBlow [reference](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126084/is-there-a-story-behind-the-misquote-luke-i-am-your-father/126208?noredirect=1#comment315460_126208) :) (j/k, of course.)

Comment: Hey, whoever sent over the phat bounty - thanks!